# Cannot use bgcolor in local scope

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I intend to color bars which fall between Start and End dates. These dates are fetched using various arrays. So a loop becomes imminent to get the dates and time from arrays to use them. However I can't BGColor inside a loop though Vline works fine.
Please help me with a solution. Thanks

```
//version=5
indicator('Loss Plotting', overlay=true,max_lines_count=500)
t1 = timestamp('GMT+530',2019,1,1,0,0,0)
t2 = timestamp('GMT+530',2019,1,1,0,0,0)
weekdaysOnly = input(true)
useVline = input(false)
dayIsOk = not weekdaysOnly or dayofweek != dayofweek.saturday and dayofweek != dayofweek.sunday
arrayYearfrom  = array.from(2019,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022)
arrayMonthfrom  = array.from(12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,12)
arrayDayfrom  = array.from(30,26,23,21,17,14,11,8,4,1,28,25,21,19,15,12,11,7,4,1,28,25,22,18,15,12,9,5,2,1,28,25,22,18,16,12,9,6,2,29,27)
arrayStartTimeHour  = array.from(9,17,12,6,12,19,3,12,8,3,9,15,22,7,17,2,9,15,20,3,13,22,7,15,21,2,10,19,6,16,23,5,11,18,4,14,0,8,14,19,3)
arrayStartTimeMins  = array.from(36,40,29,21,18,22,42,31,47,48,41,27,26,17,6,11,21,0,44,59,0,48,57,26,16,52,10,54,45,32,55,30,12,43,17,49,39,28,16,51,31)
arrayYearto  = array.from(2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022)
arrayMonthto  = array.from(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,12)
arrayDayto  = array.from(4,31,28,26,22,19,16,13,9,6,3,30,26,24,20,16,16,12,9,5,3,30,26,23,20,16,14,10,6,6,2,29,27,23,20,16,13,10,7,4,31)
arrayEndTimeHour  = array.from(10,18,1,7,13,19,3,11,19,2,8,14,21,4,0,20,4,11,17,23,6,14,22,6,14,20,2,8,17,2,11,18,0,6,12,21,6,16,0,6,11)
arrayEndTimeMins = array.from(6,10,8,17,18,54,18,14,7,22,51,57,21,33,37,57,44,30,29,28,14,3,29,44,2,15,5,50,10,29,21,43,39,14,50,7,36,2,4,16,47)
for i= 0 to array.size(arrayYearfrom)-1
    t1 := timestamp('GMT+530', array.get(arrayYearfrom,i), array.get(arrayMonthfrom,i), array.get(arrayDayfrom,i), array.get(arrayStartTimeHour,i), array.get(arrayStartTimeMins,i), 00)
    t2 := timestamp('GMT+530', array.get(arrayYearto,i), array.get(arrayMonthto,i), array.get(arrayDayto,i), array.get(arrayEndTimeHour,i), array.get(arrayEndTimeMins,i), 00)
    timeIsOk = time >= t1 and time <= t2
    bgcolor(not useVline and timeIsOk and dayIsOk ? color.orange : na, transp=80)
    if useVline and timeIsOk and dayIsOk
        line.new(bar_index, low * .9999, bar_index, high * 1.0001, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, #FF8000ff, line.style_solid, 1)
```

Comment: What's the point of using `bgcolor()` in a for loop? You cannot change the background color multiple times on the same bar. Maybe use a variable to get the final decision and then change the background color in the global scope.

Comment: Oh! My idea is to color all the bars between the two dates just like the vline function draws on those bars, which does it correctly. Totally clueless how to achieve the same with BGcolor or any other similar function.

Comment: `bgcolor()` will change the background color of the current bar. So you need a variable to start coloring on one bar and then stop coloring on another.